# Filtering a range in Julia

Tags: filter, range, julia

I have some MWE below. What I want is to have a subsection of a range, interact with the rest of the range, but not itself.

For instance if the range is `1:100`, I want to have a for loop that will have each index in `4:6`, interact with all values of `1:100` BUT NOT `4:6`.

I want to do this using ranges/filters to avoid generating temporary arrays.

In my case the total range is the number of atoms in the system. The sub-range, is the atoms in a specific molecule. I need to do calculations where each atom in a molecule interacts with all other atoms, but not the atoms in the same molecule.

### Further

I am trying to avoid using if statements because that messes up parallel codes. Doing this with an if statement would be

```
for i=4:6
    for j = 1:100
        if j == 4 || j==5 || j==6
            continue
        end
        println(i, " ", j)
    end
end
```

I have actual indexing in my code, I would never hardcode values like the above... But I want to avoid that `if` statement.

### Trials

The following does what I want, but I now realize that using `filter` is bad when it comes to memory and the amount used scales linearly with `b`.

```
a = 4:6
b = 1:100
for  i in a
    for j in filter((b) -> !(b in a),b) 
        print(i, " ", j) 
    end
end
```

Is there a way to get the double for loop I want where the outer is a sub-range of the inner, but the inner does not include the outer sub-range and most importantly is fast and does not create alot of memory usage like filter does?

Comment: [InvertedIndices.jl](https://github.com/mbauman/InvertedIndices.jl) does this (and lots more). Also, be aware that if you are performing linear algebra operations that can be sent to BLAS or LAPACK, then it is typically faster to use temporary memory allocations if it allows you to use those libraries.

Comment: I basically just do additional nested for loops. The one time I need a `norm` I just do it myself since it is a small `norm`, and that code isn't a bottleneck. The bottleneck is a nested for loop with complex arithmetic. It is the sheer size of the call that makes it a bottleneck though.

Your link looks exactly like what I am after. I do like the addons that the Julia community has added its sphere of capabilities

Comment: @ColinTBowers I can't get the package to run :(

Comment: I should have added that it is not registered, so you'll need to clone it manually from the github page (I'm assuming when you say "can't get it to run" you mean that you can't get it using the package manager - it compiles fine for me on v1.1). I'm guessing Matt probably thought it was too short to be worth registering (it's only about 40 lines of code from memory).

Comment: 108 lines but some of us are incompetent :S

Comment: There's a strong case to be made that it should be registered. I just went to file an issue, but of course it turns out there is already an open issue for this (only a month or two old), so hopefully it'll get registered when Matt has a spare moment. :-)

Comment: InvertedIndices is elegant enough to belong in base Julia, but it does splat an index as currently implemented, and so it does potentially use memory more than a pure integer Range would when used as a loop iterator. Perhaps the original code for the MWE is CPU bound more than memory bound?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about creating a custom iterator?
Note that example below needs some adjustments depending on how you define the exception lists (for example for long list with non continues indices you should use binary search).

```
struct RangeExcept
       start::Int
       stop::Int
       except::UnitRange{Int}
end

function Base.iterate(it::RangeExcept, (el, stop, except)=(it.except.start > 1 ? it.start : it.except.stop+1, it.stop, it.except))
    new_el = el+1
    if new_el in except
        new_el = except.stop+1
    end 
    el > stop && return nothing
    return (el, (new_el, stop,except))
end
```

Now let us test the code:

```
julia> for i in RangeExcept(1,10,3:7)
           println(i)
           end
1
2
8
9
10
```

Answer (score 3):

If memory usage is really a concern, consider two for loops using the range components:

```
systemrange = 1:50
moleculerange = 4:12
for i in systemrange[1]:moleculerange[1]-1
    println(i)
end
for i in moleculerange[end]+1:systemrange[end]
    println(i)
end
```

You might be able to do each loop in its own thread.

Comment: An issue with this though is making it parallel. It is worth making the whole thing parallel, but it won't be worth making only a small portion of it parallel. I would need to implement if statements to avoid trying to make the very small portion of it parallel since that would actually be slower